# How can I access data stored in a Rails app, that I created, on a seperate website?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have recently created a Rails application to handle parent comments for a company I work for. Each comment is given a score (1-10) by a moderator, I am trying to create a window on an html page that will randomly display a comment in the database as long as it has a score of at least 7. The rails app also has User authorization requirements to be able to view the database of comments.

I know this is possible but I only recently learned Ruby on Rails and am rather new to the html world as well. I am extremely willing to learn something like jquery or ajax if that is what is needed to make this work. I just need some direction so I can get started displaying the comments. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could have an action in your CommentsController like this:

```
def random_high_rated
  @comment = Comment.where(score: 7..10).sample
end
```

Your route in config/routes would look something like this:

```
resources :comments do
  collection do
    get '/random_high_rated'
  end
end
```

And you would access it at:

```
yoursite.com/comments/random_high_rated
```

Make a view at app/views/comments/random_high_rated.html.erb

And in it:

```
<%= @comment %>
```

EDIT:

Read through this tutorial and you'll be able to write your own code in no time!

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: This will render out a page that has a table that displays every comment with a score of 7-10 correct? I am trying to get them to display randomly in a box I made on the html website, is that possible?

Comment: No, it `randomly display a comment in the database as long as it has a score of at least 7.`

Comment: Ok I have it set up and it is showing just one random comment on the page I have set up for it :D Thank you for that!

Comment: How can get it to just display the quote on the website in the div I want it in without showing the layout view of the rails app as well?

Also I am having an issue with user permissions....I have to be logged in as an admin currently to see the random quote, any way I can set it up to have it's own permission?

Comment: you can search "rails specify different layout in views", and "rails skip authentication for one action". Theyre pretty specific questions to your setup as well. Mention how you are doing authentication, potentially which gem youre using, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Make a unique page in your Rails website (lets call it site no.1), display it in an iframe on site no.2

Option 2: Make a url in site no.1 that gives you JSON, XML, or even just some html, and use an AJAX call from site no.2 to pull it in.

If you've never used AJAX before, you might find using jQuery makes it easier to work with. See the [jQuery AJAX Methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) for more information. Other libraries might be better, but that's the one I've used.

Sorry if the answer is a bit general, but it's a bit of a general question.

Comment: Option 1 seems like it would make a bit more sense to me since I don't know almost anything about Json, xml, or ajax....but option 2 seems like it would be better. My Rails app may actually already be set up to render a JSON page. I have no idea how to use an AJAX to call it though... Any way you could point me to a resource so I could learn what I need to do?

Comment: I've added a link in my answer which may prove helpful.